# Is there any way to determine if the user is logging in via the Welcome Screen in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

For security reasons, we want to force users of our systems to use the traditional login dialog where they have to type in their user name and password, rather than allowing them access to the welcome screen (which lists the users on a machine). Is there any way to check (programmatically, preferably in C#) if the system is currently using the Welcome Screen (as opposed to the traditional Windows login dialog) ?

Comment: there is a registry key for that somewhere. the whole thing is called something like login style or home screen style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *Win7* & *Vista*, there's a registry key that has that information.

Key name: `dontdisplaylastusername`

Key location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

If the value of the key is `1` then the PC is using the [traditional login style](http://i196.photobucket.com/albums/aa86/rvmv/ManualLogOn.jpg).

Comment: That's not quite accurate. Even on systems where I'm using the classical login screen it's set to 0 (at least in XP). However, that is still a useful registry key for me, so thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my post. It's only accurate on win7 & vista (from my knowledge).

Comment: Your answer isn't technically what I asked for, but it is what I wanted in the end, since it prevents a user list from being displayed at logon.